# jqPlot - How to change background colour when selecting range on graph

Tags: jqplot

I'm using jqPlot to render a graph with zooming enabled.

For example:

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/zooming.php

In the example above, when you make a selection on the graph, the graph canvas is painted in grey (apart from the selection).  Does anyone know how to customise this colour?

I've been unable to find which jqPlot CSS option to tweak in jquery.jqplot.css.

Comment: +1 interesting. I wonder why would you want to change it? To me it looks perfect as it is. Although I would also like to know how to do it.

Comment: @Boro - My MFC application uses IE (< IE8) internally to render HTML pages.  When I zoom in, I've noticed the grey shading is no longer there.  So I've been looking for a way to add the grey back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that no css is involved in this particular process of painting. Though there is one class which can point you in the right direction. My suspect is the `jqplot-zoom-canvas` class. Though I think that the painting is defaulted to grey.

Thus, I see only two options:

1. Changing the painting directly in the jqplot script.
2. Or on painting of zoom selection start change the colour of the `jqplot-zoom-canvas` then change it back to default on painting zoom stop. But I do not know if there are hooks for these sort of events. Therefore, you might actually be left with only the option no. 1.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  I'd go for option 1.  Looks like the bit to change is "ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'; " in "function drawZoomBox()" in "jqplot.cursor.js".

Comment: @jpen Cool. Did you manage to make it work for you the way you wanted?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't make it work the way I wanted.  That's because my IE version is < IE8 and it doesn't support transparency.  If I change the "ctx.fillStyle" setting to not using rgba() then the resulting shade just hides my histogram.  For now I go without the nice grey shading.