# jqPlot - How to make vertical bars to widen as I zoom in

Tags: jqplot

I have two vertical bar charts (created using jqPlot) in my HTML page.

They are similar to the following example (except mine uses bars instead of lines):

http://www.assembla.com/code/MUN/subversion/node/blob/js/jqplot/examples/zoomProxy.html?rev=985

In the example above, the bottom chart is used to control the top one.  Mine works the same way.

Typically both of my charts contain over 200 x axis entries (they are passed the same dataset) and the width of each bar is set to 6px.

The problem is that when I zoom in, the bars stay thin (i.e., 6px).  What I would like to achieve is to make the bars to widen as I zoom in.  I've tried setting barWidth to null as follows:

```
// BarRenderer.
rendererOptions : {
    ...
    barWidth: null, // width of the bars.  null to calculate automatically.
    ...
}
```

However this doesn't seem to do what it says.

Does anyone have a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you tried to set the width directly yourself? If setting to null doesn't work, then I assume you could scale them accordingly to the zoom level assuming first some starting width (e.g. 6 as in your case).

Comment: @Boro Both of my plots are set to 900px wide.  If I can find how many bars will be rendered in my top plot when a user has performed a zoom, then I should be able to calculate the width of each bar against the canvas size.  So I see something like this would work: Catch zoom event → Find bar count to draw → Calculate each bar width → Update jqPlot option to use this new bar width → Replot.  I'll do some more investigation.

Comment: Your thinking is right. This is the way to go. I only am worried that you will not be able to avoid the trouble of changing the script itself, as I couldn't find no zoom event yesterday. I think everything is just painted, as we already talked in http://stackoverflow.com/q/10334135/613495 If you add your methods that are called e.g. at start and end of this `drawZoomBox()"` method you should be fine. Please do share if you arrive at a satisfactory solution. I think zoom events (and others) are important things which `jqPlot` guys should consider adding in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary workaround, you could try the modifications suggested in [issue 513](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/513/bar-width-doesnt-change-when-resizing-the). (The [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/pull-request/9/fix-for-issue-513) was rejected, because there should be a more optimized way to do this.)

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  I've tried both of the modifications but unfortunately they make my vertical bars too wide (even without doing a zoom).

Answer (score 0):

I must say I do not have a solution to this one. But maybe of some help would be if you would set `constrainZoomTo = 'y'` this way user sees what is going on, i.e. that he will zoom only the y part of the plot.

Other solution is writing this behaviour yourself. But to be honest I wouldn't know where to start with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the zooming is possible with bar charts, The bar width will be same no matter how deeper you zoom, zoom is meaning full for line charts specially.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  However in my case I have horizontal lines (using canvasOverlay) over my vertical bars and if each bar were a bit wider (e.g., 15px), it'd make it easier to see where the lines and the bars intersect.  At the moment, it's hard to see.